# Describing an action on the Weyl group $W(T)=N_G(T)/T$ for different maximal tori $T$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, weyl-group

While trying to understand more the structure of reductive group, I came upon the situation that I describe below. I can't find a mistake in my dissertation, however I arrive to an absurd conclusion. Would somebody agree to read the following and tell me where I assumed something impossible / concluded something wrong ?

---

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over an algebraically closed field. Fix $T_0$ a maximal torus, and denote by $W_0:=W(T_0)=N_G(T_0)/T_0$ the associated Weyl group. Assume that there exists an element $w_0\in W_0$ of order $2$ which is not in the center of $W_0$.

Let $n_0\in N_G(T_0)$ be a representative of $w_0$, and consider $\phi:G\xrightarrow{\sim} G$ the conjugation-by-$n_0$ automorphism. Naturally, the torus $T_0$ is $\phi$-stable, and $\phi$ induces the conjugation-by-$w_0$ automorphism of $W_0$.

Let me now consider another maximal torus $T=\,^gT_0$ for some $g\in G$. Associated to it, we have another description of the Weyl group $W:=W(T)=N_G(T)/T \simeq \, ^gW_0$. Note that we also have $N_G(T) = \, ^gN_G(T_0)$.

We make the assumption that $T$ is also $\phi$-stable, so that $\phi$ also induces an action on $W$ naturally. It means that $g^{-1}\phi(g)$ lies in $N_G(T_0)$, I denote this element by $\tilde{n_0}$. Eventually, I assume that $\tilde{n_0}$ also has image $w_0$ in $W_0$. It implies that $\tilde{n_0}n_0$ lies in $T_0$, because $w_0$ has order $2$.

Let me now look at the action of $\phi$ on $W$. Let me consider $\nu\in N_G(T)$ and write $\nu=g\nu_0g^{-1}$ for some $\nu_0\in N_G(T_0)$. I have

$$\begin{align}
\phi(\nu)=\phi(g)\phi(\nu_0)\phi(g)^{-1} & = g\tilde{n_0}\,\phi(\nu_0)\,\tilde{n_0}^{-1}g^{-1}\\
& = g\tilde{n_0}\,n_0\nu_0n_0^{-1}\,\tilde{n_0}^{-1}g^{-1}\\
& = (g\tilde{n_0}n_0g^{-1})(g\nu_0g^{-1})(gn_0^{-1}\tilde{n_0}^{-1}g^{-1})
\end{align}$$

Because $\tilde{n_0}n_0$ lies in $T_0$, both the first and last parentheses are in $^gT_0=T$. Moreover, the middle parenthesis is just $\nu$. Now, $\nu$ normalizes $T$ so we may rewrite it under the form $\nu\cdot \text{sth in }T$.
This last observation means that $\phi$ acts like $\mathrm{id}$ on $W$. But that is absurd : if it did, it would also act as identity on $W_0$, meaning that $w_0$ would be in the center of $W_0$, that is a contradiction.

So, where has something gone wrong in my arguments ?

---

**Edit:** An example, as demanded in the comments.

I consider $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ with $\mathrm{char}(k)\not = 2$, and I assume that $n=2k+1$ is odd. I consider $T_0$ the usual maximal torus consisting of diagonal matrices, and $W_0$ is identified with $\mathfrak S_n$. I consider $w_0$ defined by the formula $w_0(i)=n+1-i$. As a representative in $N_G(T_0)$, I consider $n_0$ the matrix having antidiagonal filled with $1$'s.
Now, I put
$$g = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &        &       &        &        &        & 1\\
  & \unicode{x22f1} &       &        &        & \unicode{x22F0} &  \\
  &        & 1     &        & 1      &        &  \\
  &        &       & 1      &        &        &  \\
  &        & 1     &        & -1     &        &  \\
  & \unicode{x22F0} &       &        &        & \unicode{x22f1} &  \\
1 &        &       &        &        &        & -1
\end{bmatrix} 
\quad 
g^{-1} =
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &        &       &        &        &        & 1\\
  & \unicode{x22f1} &       &        &        & \unicode{x22F0} &  \\
  &        & 1     &        & 1      &        &  \\
  &        &       & 2      &        &        &  \\
  &        & 1     &        & -1     &        &  \\
  & \unicode{x22F0} &       &        &        & \unicode{x22f1} &  \\
1 &        &       &        &        &        & -1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
This shape is possible because $n$ is odd. The matrix $g$ is invertible because of the assumption on the characteristic. Its inverse is given by the matrix on the right. I may now compute $g^{-1}\phi(g)$ which gives me the antidiagonal matrix having coefficients, from bottom left to top right, $k$ times $-1$ and $k+1$ times $1$. It is a generalized permutation matrix, so it lies in $N_G(T_0)$. In means that $T:=\,^gT_0$ is stable by $\phi$. Moreover, let us note that $\tilde{n_0}:=g^{-1}\phi(g)$ also is a representative of $w_0$, just as in the situation I considered above.

We may further compute $T$ explicitly. It is the subgroup (maximal torus) consisting of all cross-shaped invertible matrices (ie. with coefficients on the diagonals only) which are invariant under 180° rotation.

---

**Edit2:** Partial answer and thoughts.

I think that my mistake lies in "if $\phi$ acts like $\mathrm{id}$ on $W$ then it must act like $\mathrm{id}$ in $W_0$ as well".

Say, generally speaking, that $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ is an endomorphism of $G$ having $T_0$ and $T:=\,^gT_0$ as two maximal $\phi$-stable tori, so that $\tilde{n_0}:=g^{-1}\phi(g) \in N_G(T_0)$. Assume also that $\phi$ acts like $\mathrm{id}$ on $W$. It means precisely that $\forall \nu \in N_G(T), \;\nu^{-1}\phi(\nu)\in T$.

In terms of $T_0$, it means that $\forall \nu_0\in N_G(T_0),\; \nu_0^{-1}\tilde{n_0}\phi(\nu_0)\tilde{n_0}^{-1}\in T_0$. In other words, the composition of the conjugation by $\tilde{n_0}$ with $\phi$ induces the identity on $W_0$. Thus, $\phi$ acts like conjugation by (the image of) $\tilde{n_0}^{-1}$ on $W_0$, which may not be the identity. This is consistent with my situation above, where $\phi$ acts like conjugation by $w_0$.

The conclusion is that the action of an endomorphism on a Weyl group actually depends on the choice of the stable maximal torus ; that was unexpected for me.

Comment: "We make the assumption that T is also ϕ-stable". Why can you make this assumption?

Comment: @tobiaskildetoft I merely assume that I am in a situation where this holds (I can find another $phi$-stable maximal torus). Given that I arrive to an absurd conclusion, either I did an impossible assumption, either I did a mistake in my reasoning. I'm trying to find out which one

Comment: Well, do you have an example where the assumption holds?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I do, see the edit at the end of my question.